# how to find a specific column name from a table whose column value is matched?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with columns as follows..

1. id
2. person1
3. person2

let's say there are 2 records having values...

```
id1 - 2222 - 4444  
id2 - 3333 - 6666
```

I want to modify the value of that cell whose value is '4444' and id is 'id1'

Comment: So how do you want the table to look at the end of it?

Comment: @Mureinik The value '4444' will change to the required value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression on only update the appropriate columns:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    person1 = CASE person1 WHEN '4444' THEN 'new value' ELSE person1 END,
       person2 = CASE person2 WHEN '4444' THEN 'new value' ELSE person2 END
WHERE  id = 'id1' AND
       '4444' IN (person1, person2)
```

Comment: I have about 49 columns in that table. Here I just give an example of it.

Comment: @KishorePatra . . . Then you should ask another question, with more representative sample data and desired results.  This question is quite specific and Mureinik has correctly answered it.  Editing the question would be rude the those who have already answered it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Using Mureinik logic I have solved it. But just had to write a little php script.Thanks Mureinik.

Answer (score 2):

@Mureinik has given the answer. But as you asked for other 49 columns how to make this query then you can prepare the dynamic query and then execute it. Below is the same query mentioned by @Mureinik but created dynamically:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
               CONCAT(UN.column_name, ' = CASE ', UN.column_name,' WHEN ''4444'' THEN ''1111'' ELSE ', UN.column_name,' END'))
    INTO @sql
    FROM (
      SELECT table_name, column_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        where table_name = 'MyTable'
        AND column_name like 'person%') UN;

SET @sql =  CONCAT('UPDATE mytable SET ', @sql, ' WHERE  id = ''id1''');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c6e75/7)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table
SET person2 = 'new value'
WHERE person2 = '4444' and id = 'id1'
```

Or do you mean that you want to update all those cells that have a certain value (here '4444'), whatever the column is?

Comment: I want to update all those cells that have a certain value (here '4444'), whatever the column is...